# Can't connect to pi via hostname

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, ping

I have samba installed, and have also followed all the steps here: http://elinux.org/RPi_Advanced_Setup

However I still can't access the pi by hostname. I get the message: Ping request could not find host raspberry.local. Please check the name and try again.

I've also tried with the name "raspberry" but that doesn't work either. Can anyone help me out? I'm trying to ping from a windows machine.

EDIT: Hostname is raspberry, I am able to ping the Pi by IP, and bonjour is installed on the windows machine.

EDIT2: Something else strange is when I type `host <myhostname>` into the terminal I get the response `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

EDIT3: I can also ping my windows machine from my pi by host name... grrr

Comment: Do you have itunes or bonjour installed? Can you ping or SSH using the IP address? Do you use mcafee? Do you have a firewall?

Comment: What is your hostname?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Bonjour is installed and I can ping it by IP.

Comment: @Milliways raspberry

Comment: If your router always  gives the Pi the same IP address (most do or can be configured to do so) you could add an entry to the hosts file on your PC? Also, to rule out the obvious have you rebooted the PC and Pi?

Comment: Do you have `avahi-daemon` installed?

Comment: @Rumesh Yup, I did `sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon`

Comment: @SteveRobillard I can't set a static IP to it I don't think.

Comment: Are your raspberry and windows machine on the same subnet?  mDNS (avahi/bonjour) usually doesn't work across subnets.

Comment: @Hydraxan14 Good point, they actually aren't on the same sub right now... strange.. But if this is the case how can I ping my windows machine from my Pi?

Comment: @CapnJack This is the difference between sending to one (unicast), [sending to many (multicast)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast), and sending to all on the LAN (broadcast).  The latter two don't work across subnets.  Pinging a single address is unicast, so it succeeds.  mDNS is ["Multicast Domain Name Service"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS).  Hence, it doesn't work for machines on a different subnet.

Comment: But then wouldn't pinging my pi from my windows machine be unicast as well?